# Object changing scale in Rendered mode

Tags: modeling, objects, blender-internal-render-engine

As you can see from my model I am very new to blender, but I feel I'm progressing well. But this problem is slowing me down as it's very distracting.

I have a scene with various parts and everything lines up fine  in all modes except Rendered. I have made sure I have deleted all keyframes, and hit ctrl-a to apply LocRotScale where I want it, but as soon as I go to rendered mode or try an actual render, the main cube seems to get smaller so then nothing lines up.

I have searched a lot for a solution but only found the obvious answers, which haven't worked for me. I have even remade the cube again but I still get the same problem, which just confused me even more.

Can someone please cure my noobness??

Many thanks.

Update: Here is a link to the blend file. Its more than likely terrible so please don't laugh :) 
https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B8cLVpkzaATbcDM4YUJhZzFFV28&usp=sharing

[image: How it looks in Rendered View]

Comment: could you upload the blendfile?

Comment: Thanks Gladys, I have updated my question to include the blend file link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have enabled **Warp** in the Influence panel under Texture.15's tab

[image]

With that map you are displacing the geometry's vertices. I can't tell you why a Wrap with 0 influence mess all up and disabling it fix the problem, but is definetly that option that you have to check.

[image]

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much for taking the time to look through all my mess!